# Equalizer to "cap" frequency loudness?

Tags: audio, audio-editing

I have tinnitus. Sharp sounds above 4 kHz make it WAY worse.

Almost every movie & game have loud sharp, screeching sounds.

I've installed many equalizers, such as [APO](https://equalizerapo.com/). They have gradual dampening, so no matter how loud or quiet a sound is, the EQ always dampens the sound with [x]dB. **If I dampen >4kHz enough to protect my tinnitus, then human speech becomes almost impossible to hear.**

**Is there an equalizer out there, which simply "caps" the maximum volume of a certain frequency?** I want the program to leave the sound as it is, unmodified, until the volume of the selected frequency band reaches above the "maximum allowed volume". At THAT point, I want the program to step in, and dampen those frequencies.

Illustration:[image]

Best regards!

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! Please mention constraints - e.g. the APO tool you reference containst screendumps that look like Windows - are you looking only for Windows solutions, or also e.g. linux tools?

Comment: What you're looking for is known as a **multi-band compressor**. idk any that will sit in Windows APO structure, sorry. Usually, they are available as VST, AU, etc as plugins to more 'pro' audio environments. I know how you could do this on Mac, very easily but not free.